# Media queries won't work

Tags: html, css

I have this simple media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1600px) {

   body {
      font-size: 14px;
   }

}
```

But this just doesn't work. My screen resolution is 1600x900, so it should work, I think. What the hell is wrong here? I put this on the end of .css file, I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the HTML file... I don't know what else should i do to make this working.

Answer (score 2):

[`min-width` and `max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#width) refer to the width of the *window*, not of the *screen*. [`@media screen`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) means that the styles apply to the "screen" medium (as opposed to the "print" medium for example).

To target the resolution, you can use [`min-resolution` and `max-resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#resolution).